# R symbol suddenly stopped working - Android Studio

Tags: android, manifest

i haven't done anything and suddenly it doesnt recognize R symbol, also showing me the Manifest which has been built under the build folder which is for debug. 
ive been looking for an answer over an hour, none of the existing solution on stack worked for me

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have an invalid `android:theme` value in the manifest somewhere, so the resource build fails, and you get that `R` error.

Comment: R isn't generated and hence doesn't exist if there's an error somewhere in the project. Your problem is in your Manifest file. It can't find mentioned Theme, check in style if the theme mentioned in Manifest file exist.

Comment: yes there's a style theme but its FIX, im wonder what is the problem!

Comment: Make sure you fix it in the right file. The manifest you have open in that screenshot is not the right one. Look at the warning in the yellow banner at the top, under the tabs.

Comment: I have run across similar problems. Sometimes just cleaning and rebuilding the project works. Other times, I have just exited and restarted Android Studio.

Comment: yes you are right, I'm editing the right manifest, its a theme that only works on SDK 21 or higher, my min SDK was on 15, I've changed it to minSDK 21 and its got fine, thanks a lot

Comment: Please show your solution as an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was AppTheme.Main which is a Transition Theme doesnt work with Android >21 so you have to set the MinSDK in gradle on 21 then it will be ok.
Mainly the R problem is for XML files. so I've set the MinSDK on 21 and it's got ok.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the name of "debug" folder inside project folder if nothing else work